# How to install Oracle 18c client on Windows 10

Tags: oracle, windows-10, client, oracle18c

I need to install the Oracle 18c client on a VM with Windows 10. I´ve already downloaded the client files, but there´s no have any setup.exe inside the folders. Can someone help me? I need only to copy the files for my computer and to set the register? How can i do that?

Regards

Comment: Have you looked at the [Oracle Database Client Installation Guide for Windows][1] (18c)?
The fact that you say there is no 'setup.exe' in the unzipped folders seems to indicate you got the wrong file.  What is the name of the zip file you downloaded?  (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ntcli/procedure-for-installing-oracle-db-client.html#GUID-3C5A8697-0BFB-461A-A7DB-EDACC0C4099D)

Answer (score 2):

Either you have downloaded  Oracle (full) Client but your download has failed and you need to download again the installation media.

Or your download has succeeded and you have downloaded Oracle *Instant* Client: in this case there is no setup.exe and you only need to follow [this](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html#ic_winx64_inst)